# DNX (rc1-final): IHttpConnectionFeature not found

Tags: azure, dnx, azure-api-apps

Using the latest rc1-final version of ASP.NET 5, I'm attempting to find the remote IP address inside an Azure API App controller method.

When running the code, 'context' is this.HttpContext, inside the controller method.

But feature is coming back null, since the feature doesn't exist.

```
    IHttpConnectionFeature feature = context.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>();
```

Does anything have to be enabled in the configuration to have this feature be available?

Thanks,
Kirk

Comment: Could you post your startup.cs? I my case it is working so I could check it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The following code works for me:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        if (!UserID.HasValue)
        {
            UpdateRemoteIp(HttpContext);
            var remoteIpAddress = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>()?.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
            if (remoteIpAddress == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot determine client IP");
            }
            await _userService.LoginAnonymous(remoteIpAddress);
            string url = UriHelper.GetDisplayUrl(Request);
            return Redirect(url);
        }
        PrepareViewModel();
        return View("Index", ViewModel);
    }

 private static void UpdateRemoteIp(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var xForwardedForHeaderValue = httpContext.Request.Headers.GetCommaSeparatedValues(XForwardedForHeaderName);
        if (xForwardedForHeaderValue != null && xForwardedForHeaderValue.Length > 0)
        {
            IPAddress ipFromHeader;
            int? port;
            if (IPAddressWithPortParser.TryParse(xForwardedForHeaderValue[0], out ipFromHeader, out port))
            {
                var connection = httpContext.Connection;
                var remoteIPString = connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(remoteIPString))
                {
                    httpContext.Request.Headers[XOriginalIPName] = remoteIPString;
                }
                if (port.HasValue)
                {
                    if (connection.RemotePort != 0)
                    {
                        httpContext.Request.Headers[XOriginalPortName] = connection.RemotePort.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    }
                    connection.RemotePort = port.Value;
                }
                connection.RemoteIpAddress = ipFromHeader;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you